# Creating a Sheet of Comments

Tags: vba, excel

**Caution, I am a novice.**

Objective: To create a "Comments" sheet that includes all comments from the current sheet selected. Here is what my sheet looks like:
[image: Source]

The way I want the sheet to look is:
[image: Preferred outcome]

The way the sheet **actually** appears is:
[image: Actual outcome]

Essentially, I do not want to use the "Parent Address" for the "Comment In" column but rather the heading above the cell. For example, I do not want $A$2 but actually want it to refer to the heading "Responsible Party". My initial thought was that I could use named ranges but it proved to be out of my capabilities.

**I am not a strong coder. Please keep this in mind.**

The code is as follows:

```
Sub ExtractComments()
Dim ExComment As Comment
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CS As Worksheet
Set CS = ActiveSheet
If ActiveSheet.Comments.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In Worksheets
  If ws.Name = "Comments" Then i = 1
Next ws

If i = 0 Then
  Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
  ws.Name = "Comments"
Else: Set ws = Worksheets("Comments")
End If

For Each ExComment In CS.Comments
  ws.Range("A1").Value = "Comment In"
  ws.Range("B1").Value = "Comment By"
  ws.Range("C1").Value = "Comment"
  With ws.Range("A1:C1")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
    .Columns.ColumnWidth = 20
  End With
  If ws.Range("A2") = "" Then
    ws.Range("A2").Value = ExComment.Parent.Address
    ws.Range("B2").Value = Left(ExComment.Text, InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":") - 1)
    ws.Range("C2").Value = Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":"))
  Else
    ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = ExComment.Parent.Address
    ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Left(ExComment.Text, InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":") - 1)
    ws.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":"))
  End If
Next ExComment
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not bad from a novice :) Try this:

```
    ...
Else: Set ws = Worksheets("Comments")
End If

Dim iRow As Long   ' you have a better control this way directly specifying the target cell

' header needs to written only once - out of loop

ws.Range("A1").Value = "Comment In"
ws.Range("B1").Value = "Comment By"
ws.Range("C1").Value = "Comment"

With ws.Range("A1:C1")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
    .Columns.ColumnWidth = 20
End With

iRow = 2        ' first empty row 
For Each ExComment In CS.Comments
    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = CS.Cells(1, ExComment.Parent.Column)  ' value in 1st row of column of comment
    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Left(ExComment.Text, InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":") - 1)
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":"))
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next ExComment

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great especially thanks to the ability to change the header row and the target cell. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just one change to add the header value, and shortened your code a little by working up from the bottom when adding comments, and remove some stuff from the loop.

```
Sub ExtractComments()

Dim ExComment As Comment
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CS As Worksheet
Set CS = ActiveSheet
If ActiveSheet.Comments.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In Worksheets
  If ws.Name = "Comments" Then i = 1
Next ws

If i = 0 Then
  Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
  ws.Name = "Comments"
Else: Set ws = Worksheets("Comments")
End If

With ws
    .Range("A1").Value = "Comment In"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Comment By"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Comment"
    With .Range("A1:C1")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
        .Columns.ColumnWidth = 20
    End With
    For Each ExComment In CS.Comments
        .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = CS.Cells(1, ExComment.Parent.Column)
        .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = Left(ExComment.Text, InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":") - 1)
        .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":"))
    Next ExComment
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ha got sidetracked halfway through and 3 other answers have probably covered everything I did.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
      ws.Range("A2").Value = ExComment.Parent.End(xlUp).Value
```

so:

```
    If ws.Range("A2") = "" Then
      ws.Range("A2").Value = ExComment.Parent.End(xlUp).Value
      ws.Range("B2").Value = Left(ExComment.Text, InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":") - 1)
      ws.Range("C2").Value = Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":"))
    Else
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = ExComment.Parent.End(xlUp).Value
      ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Left(ExComment.Text, InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":") - 1)
      ws.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":"))
    End If
```

while you could consider the following refactoring of your code

```
Sub ExtractComments()
    If ActiveSheet.Comments.count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets("Comments")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
        ws.Name = "Comments"
    End If

    Dim ExComment As Comment
    With ws
        With .Range("A1:C1")
        .Value = Array("Comment In", "Comment By", "Comment")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
        .Columns.ColumnWidth = 20
        End With

        For Each ExComment In ActiveSheet.Comments
            .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 3) = Array(ExComment.Parent.End(xlUp).Value, _
                                                                        Left(ExComment.Text, InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":") - 1), _
                                                                        Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":")))
        Next ExComment
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works with the data in the example, but be careful with `xlUp` if there are any empty data cells

Comment: @CallumDA, I answered after given data example.